# How to get call stack in VSC debugger? console.trace() is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, callstack

If I'm paused in the VSC debugger I can't get the call stack with `console.trace()`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a call stack tab at the bottom of the debugger tab. Expand this!

[image]